# How to reduce content of exists PDF page in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I convert HTML to PDF, but when i look PDF it has 2 page because content is a bit longer for one page. But i want to fit content to one page.

I tried this but it doesn't help me.

```csharp
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
                    
                    pdf.LoadFromFile(pdfPath);
        
        
                    PdfDocument newPdf = new PdfDocument();
        
                    foreach (PdfPageBase page in pdf.Pages)
                    {
        
                        PdfPageBase newPage = newPdf.Pages.Add(PdfPageSize.A1, new Spire.Pdf.Graphics.PdfMargins(0));
        
        
                        PdfTextLayout loLayout = new PdfTextLayout();
                        
                        loLayout.Layout = PdfLayoutType.OnePage;
        
                        page.CreateTemplate().Draw(newPage, new PointF(0, 0), loLayout);
        
                    }
        
                    newPdf.SaveToFile(newPdfPath);
```

Comment: Are you using pdfsharp or itextsharp?

Comment: this is spire.pdf. any advice ?

Comment: Can someone help ?